# Splitting a large c++ program into several components

Tags: c++, dll, dylib, decoupling

I have a c++ program that consists of many .cpp & .h files.

I'd like to introduce some physical decoupling by taking a bunch of .cpp files for a certain feature of the program, and compile that feature into a seperate .dll / dylib.

When doing this, the dylib will not link, because it calls many (100s) functions in the "main" application. What are my options to solve this?  (platform: osx, windows and linux)

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy answer to this question. Undoing a [big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) is an art not a science. The basic approach I would begin with in your place would be to add a third component that included those 100's of functions and make that a dependency of both the main application and your feature dll. This can be a rabbit hole however as you try to identify what are truly the "leaf" components of your system.

[Martin Fowler's info on refactoring](http://refactoring.com/) has many good resources.